# Azure Send Test Message To Android with FCM - Results in The Token obtained from the token provider is wrong

Tags: cordova, azure, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have configured a notification hub in Azure to send messages to Apple and Android devices.

When sending test messages in the portal or VS.NET, the Apple messages go through with no problem, while the Android messages return an error message:

```
The Token obtained from the Token from token provider is wrong.
```

I double checked the API key to make sure that the one configured in the Azure notification hub is the correct server key from the Firebase Console under the Cloud Messaging tab.

I see the target device is registered using the server explorer. Not sure what could be wrong. I deleted the Firebase app and recreated it, but it did not help.

Not sure where to look next. Thanks.

Comment: I just got this error on Azure as well as I was testing out UWP Push Notifications and came here through a Google search. Its either coincidental we both just experienced this error or maybe Azure is having a problem.

Comment: Just a coincidence. The problem is that my app details weren't exactly matching what was in the store. Hence I would check that the details you have registered in the Play Store match your local app details in the Manifest.

Comment: I assume that you have a token generated by the Android app, if you use that token and send an HTTP request using the API key that you specify in Azure portal does it work? The error you are seeing is not one that FCM returns so I'd be sure that you can send using HTTP then troubleshoot Azure portal

Comment: Have you been able to solve it? Can you send a push to the device [via the command line](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/?hl=en#send_a_request_from_the_command_line_for_fcm_to_push_a_message)?

Comment: Solved it - stupid mistake but easy to think the app id is what the push notifications needed instead of the projectID from the firebase dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out that the PushNotification plugin needed the projectID/sender id (all #'s)  from the Firebase dashboard not the app id (unique name) from the Play store listing .

Now push notifications are being received

Comment: ProjectId and SenderId are two separate numbers.  Could you clarify which one you used?